# Python-Docker container cannot connect to MariaDB-Docker container

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, mariadb, docker-network

I'm trying to get my dockerized python-script to get data from an also dockerized mariadb.

I know this should be possible with networks or links. However, due to links being deprecated (According to [the Docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/network/links/)), I'd rather not use links.

`docker-compose`:

```
version: "3.7"

services:

[...]

 mariadb:
   build: ./db
   container_name: maria_db
   expose: 
     - 3306
   environment:
     MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
     MYSQL_USER: user
     MYSQL_PASSWORD: user
   restart: always
   networks:
       - logrun_to_mariadb
[...]

 logrun_engine:
   build: ./logrun_engine
   container_name: logrun_engine
   restart: always
   networks:
     - logrun_to_mariadb

networks:
   logrun_to_mariadb:
       external: false
       name: logrun_to_mariadb
```

The `logrun_engine` container executes a python-script on startup:

```py
import mysql.connector as mariadb

class DBConnector:
   def __init__(self, dbname):
       self.mariadb_connection = mariadb.connect(host='mariadb', port='3306', user='root', password='root', database=dbname)
       self.cursor = self.mariadb_connection.cursor()

   def get_Usecases(self):
       self.cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM Test")
       tests = []
       for test in self.cursor:
           print(test) 
       print("Logrun-Engine running...")

test = DBConnector('test_db')
test.get_Usecases()
```

Whenever I run `docker-compose up -d`, my logrun_engine logs are full of the error message:

```
_mysql_connector.MySQLInterfaceError: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'mariadb' (111)
```

When I run the python script locally and connect to a local mariadb, it works with no problems, so the script should be correct.

Most answers I found concerning this error-message are that the people used `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` instead of the docker container, which I already have.

I tried with bridged networks, host networks, links etc. but apparently I haven't found the correct thing yet.

Any idea how to connect these two containers?

Comment: one thing to keep in mind here is that `mysql` is not going to start up immediately - it's going to take a bit of time to initialize the first time as it's a heavyweight DB.  After some seconds it will be ready.  Not saying that's your problem, just something to be aware of.  You might want to add retry logic to your python connection to tolerate this.

Comment: @DanielFarrell Well, I could've spent that weekend way more productive... Thanks a lot for that way too simple answer, which actually worked. Jesus, I can't believe that this was actually the case!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I was just too impatient and didn't let mysql start up properly before querying the database, thanks @DanielFarrel for pointing that out. 
When I added a 10sec delay in the python script before querying the database, it magically worked...

Answer (score -1):

Sleep maybe one solution. However, it may be problematic in case db goes up slowly.

As an alternative you can use [agent](https://github.com/jmenga/docker-ansible/tree/master/ansible) that will make sure db is up before connecting to it similar to solution [here](https://github.com/jmenga/todobackend/blob/master/docker/dev/docker-compose-v2.yml).

Run:

`docker-compose up -d agent`

After agent is up you are sure db is up and you app may run:

`docker-compose up -d logrun_engine`

The solution does use [`--links`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#links), however it can be easily modified to use docker networks.